# Multiply numbers without using instructions MUL, IMUL, SHL, SHR, LOOP

Tags: assembly, x86, multiplication

Is it possible to calculate result of multiplication without using instructions MUL, IMUL, SHL, SHR, LOOP, JMP in x86 assembly language?

Comment: I guess you could implement multiplication by repeated addition.  I don't really see the point of such an exercise though.

Comment: `shl` can be simulated by adding a register to itself, hence can be used for improving performance compared to repeated addition

Comment: with infinite memory or small arguments (like 8bit * 8bit) you can implement multiplication with one `mov` instruction. (your question makes little point, you block few instructions and leave out most of them free, like `mov` and `add`, which can be used to produce almost everything else, if you are patient enough and write enough code).

Comment: yes [`mov` is Turing-complete](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~sd601/papers/mov.pdf), so you can do anything with it, not only multiplication. [There's even a compiler that only uses `mov`s](https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/movfuscator)

Answer (score 1):

The following code will multiply the contents of the registers `ecx` and `edx` and store the result in register `eax`. The content of the registers `ebx` and `edx` is destroyed:

```
  mov ebx, 1
  mov eax, 0
repeat:
  test ecx, ebx
  jz dontadd
  add eax, edx
dontadd:
  add edx, edx
  add ebx, ebx
  jnz repeat
```

> without ... LOOP

If "LOOP" does not only cover the "LOOP" instruction but any conditional jump instructions:

Doing a multiplication without conditional jump instructions is a bit more difficult but not impossible; the following example does so (Input: `ecx` and `edx`, output `eax`, the content of all registers used will be destroyed):

```
mov ebx, 1
mov eax, 0
not ecx
  # Repeat the following code 32 times:
mov esi, ebx
and esi, ecx
dec esi
and esi, edx
add eax, esi
add edx, edx
add ebx, ebx
  # (repeat the code here)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to calculate result of multiplication without using instructions MUL, IMUL, SHL, SHR, LOOP, JMP in x86 assembly language?

Yes.

Without MUL the normal approach is "SHIFT LEFT and TEST and ADD" in a loop, like this:

```
    result = 0;
    while(a > 0) {
        result = result << 1;
        if( a & 0x80000000 != 0) {
            result = result + b;
        }
        a = a << 1;
    }
```

Note that a loop like this for 32-bit integers will have (at most) 32 iterations.

You can replace these shifts with additions (e.g. `shl eax, 1` replaced with `add eax, eax`); and you can replace `LOOP` with an explicit loop (e.g. `dec ecx`, `jne next`) or unroll the loop (repeat the code 32 times). These replacements will probably improve performance.

Once you have unsigned multiplication, `IMUL` can be replaced with branches that convert the values to positive and uses unsigned multiplication. E.g. like:

```
    if(a < 0) {
        a = -a;
        if(b < 0) {
            b = -b
            return a*b;    // Unsigned multiplication
        } else {
            return -a*b;   // Unsigned multiplication
        }
    } else {
        if(b < 0) {
            b = -b
            return -a*b;   // Unsigned multiplication
        } else {
            return a*b;    // Unsigned multiplication
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hell bent against full *table lookup* and [*logarithm, addition and exponentiation*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule#Circular_slide_rules), you can still do
[*table lookup of squares and subtraction*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Quarter_square_multiplication): ab = **(a+b)²/4 - (a-b)²/4**.

Comment: So you need a lookup table of `unsigned squares[1<<16]`?  Interesting but not practical unless you have a large / fast flash ROM for a very weak microcontroller or something.  Or if your inputs are known to be small, so the table of squares can be much smaller.

Comment: `[table uint_least32_t] squares[1<<16]` If doing 16×16 straight, yes. Add in "one-level-Karatsuba" and fight the need for more than 16 bits per entry (without conditional jumps…), or do four 8×8 and align byte-wise.

Answer (score 0):

CPUs without a multiply instruction can generally do it with repeated addition but that becomes *extremely* difficult without loops.

However, since you haven't specified which *specific* CPU you're interested in, I would posit one that either has an instruction like:

```
add rt, rs, count
```

instruction which adds `rs` to `rt` exactly `count` times. That would enable you to do it without a `loop` or `jump` instruction :-)

Of course, then you could just have an `paxmul` instruction that does multiplication for you - not technically a `mul` but no doubt against the *spirit* of the question.

But, to be honest, this question may be seen as moot since you'd be hard pressed actually *trying* to find a CPU without the instructions you list.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to mention the type of CPU..! It's intel x86
Thanks for answering weird question!

Comment: well, technically the restriction here is only on `jmp` and `loop` instructions. `jz`, `je` and similar are perfectly suffucient to implement looping